# Tree drawing displays overlapping nodes

Tags: java, javafx

I want to paint a tree (n-ary) in dialog box starting from a set of TreeItems that i define and structure in a tree.

The full JavaFx code for defining the TreeItems and drawing the tree in a dialog box is the following:

```
public class treeController{
     @fxml
     public void openDialogWindowTreePreview() {
    
            AnchorPane treeGraphPane = new AnchorPane();
            treeGraphPane.setPrefWidth(600);
            treeGraphPane.setPrefHeight(400);
            List<TreeItemNode> children = new ArrayList<>();
            List<TreeItemNode> children5 = new ArrayList<>();
            List<TreeItemNode> children4 = new ArrayList<>();
    
            TreeItemNode treeItemFirstChild = new TreeItemNode("child1", new ArrayList<TreeItemNode>(), true);
    
            TreeItemNode treeItemSecondChild = new TreeItemNode("child2", new ArrayList<TreeItemNode>(), true);
    
            TreeItemNode treeItemThirdChild = new TreeItemNode("child3", new ArrayList<TreeItemNode>(), true);
            children5.add(treeItemFirstChild);
            children5.add(treeItemSecondChild);
            children5.add(treeItemThirdChild);
    
            children4.add(treeItemFirstChild);
            children4.add(treeItemSecondChild);
            children4.add(treeItemThirdChild);
            TreeItemNode treeItemForthChild = new TreeItemNode("child4", children4, true);
            TreeItemNode treeItemFifthChild = new TreeItemNode("child5", children5, true);
            TreeItemNode treeItemsixthChild = new TreeItemNode("child6", new ArrayList<TreeItemNode>(), true);
            TreeItemNode treeItemsevthChild = new TreeItemNode("child7", new ArrayList<TreeItemNode>(), true);
            children.add(treeItemFirstChild);
            children.add(treeItemSecondChild);
            children.add(treeItemThirdChild);
            children.add(treeItemForthChild);
            children.add(treeItemFifthChild);
            children.add(treeItemsixthChild);
            children.add(treeItemsevthChild);
            TreeItemNode treeItemRoot = new TreeItemNode(300/*the 1/2 of 400 width of dialog*/, 50, "root", children);
            treeItemRoot.setChild(false);
            Alert dialog = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
            dialog.setWidth(1050);
            dialog.setHeight(600);
    
            drawNodeRecursive(treeGraphPane,treeItemRoot.getX(),/*10*/treeItemRoot.getY(), treeItemRoot);
            dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(treeGraphPane);
            dialog.setResizable(true);
    
            Optional<ButtonType> result = dialog.showAndWait();
    
        }
    
        public int drawNodeRecursive(AnchorPane mainGraphTreeLayout, int x, int y, TreeItemNode parentNode) {
            
            Circle circle = new Circle(parentNode.getX(),parentNode.getY(), 15, Paint.valueOf("blue"));
            mainGraphTreeLayout.getChildren().add(circle);
            
            Text txt = new Text(x-3,y+3, String.valueOf(parentNode.getValue()));
            mainGraphTreeLayout.getChildren().add(txt);
           
            List<TreeItemNode> nodeChildrenList = parentNode.getChildren();
            int xPrime = parentNode.getX()+25;  
            for (TreeItemNode child : nodeChildrenList) {
                child.setX(xPrime);
                child.setY(parentNode.getY()+50);  
                Line line = new Line(parentNode.getX(), parentNode.getY()+5, child.getX(), child.getY());
           
                mainGraphTreeLayout.getChildren().add(line);
              
                xPrime = drawNodeRecursive(mainGraphTreeLayout,child.getX(), child.getY(), child) - 50;  
            }
            return x;
        }
```

the fxml code in main.fxml consists of an anchorPane with  a button as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>

<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="treeController">
   <children>
      <Pane prefHeight="206.0" prefWidth="281.0">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="button1" layoutX="59.0" layoutY="63.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="63.0" prefWidth="164.0" text="Button" onAction="#onDialogWindowTreePreview" />
         </children>
      </Pane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

But unfortunately the tree drawing contains **overlapping** nodes as shown in the attached image:[image: overlapping nodes tree image]

What is wrong with my `drawNodeRecursive()` method?

EDIT: as per @kleopatra request this is the remainder of the code:

```
   public class TreeItemNode {
        public int x;
        public int y;
        public String value;
        public List<TreeItemNode> children;
        public boolean isChild;
    
        public boolean isChild() {
            return isChild;
        }
    
        public void setChild(boolean child) {
            isChild = child;
        }
        public TreeItemNode( String value, List<TreeItemNode> children,boolean isChild) {
    
            this.value = value;
            this.isChild = isChild;
            this.children = children;
    
        }
 public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public List<TreeItemNode> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void setChildren(List<TreeItemNode> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }
}
```

And finally

```
public class UInterface extends Application  {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
    
        String fxmlFile = "main.fxml";
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        Parent rootNode = (Parent) loader.load(getClass().getResource(fxmlFile));

         
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootNode, 1024, 843);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch();
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Pls see EDIT, i can through the posted code reproduce the problem in my PC, i don't see why you cannot

Comment: Your `TreeItemNode` has x and y co-ordinates which you set in your `drawNodeRecursive`.  But you are reusing instances of a TreeItemNode in multiple places in your tree, so the x and y coordinates for a given instance will be set more than once.  This is very confusing.  Maybe take a look at a [tree layout library](https://github.com/abego/treelayout) to see how you could fix/improve your implementation.

Comment: How you embed the tree into a JavaFx AnchorPane in that case?

Comment: You copy the [swing tree demo implementation](https://github.com/abego/treelayout/tree/master/org.abego.treelayout.demo/src/main/java/org/abego/treelayout/demo/swing), update the `SwingDemo` class to be a JavaFX application using JavaFX code instead of Swing code, and rewrite the `TextInBoxTreePane` to use either the JavaFX scene graph or a JavaFX canvas.

Comment: what's the equivalent of Graphics of Jwt in JavaFx ? could you be more helpful here? thanks

Comment: There is no equivalent of graphics, but canvas is closest.

Comment: but then i have to rewrite the whole `https://github.com/abego/treelayout/blob/master/org.abego.treelayout/src/main/java/org/abego/treelayout/TreeLayout.java` class? isn't there a simpler solution to paint a simple random tree in JavaFx ?

Comment: You do not need to rewrite that class, only the classes I indicated earlier.  You can of course apply a different solution, I have no advice on that.

Comment: but how can i improve/fix my solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't advise trying to write your own general-purpose tree layout library.  That is a difficult and error-prone thing, which has already been done before.  Instead, use an existing library that calculates the correct layout for you.  In this answer, this is what I do, I do not provide information on how to correct your current algorithm.

The tree layout library used is the abego library:

- https://github.com/abego/treelayout

Sample code to use this in JavaFX follows.

Much of the code is from the existing abego demo applications (I did not write it).  I left out the license comment from some of the copied code for brevity, but the license (BSD) can be found at the abego github link.

I didn't make a lot of effort to make it work nicely with JavaFX.  In particular, there are no dynamic properties or listeners to changes of the trees or CSS stylesheet styling of the trees, which is what would be provided in a more feature-rich implementation.   It also follows the abego sample, which uses node sizes that are configured in the tree setup rather than dynamically calculating the size of each node (which would be an alternative implementation).

The trees themselves are drawn using the JavaFX scene graph in a Group node, there are other technologies, such as the canvas which could be used to draw the trees, I just chose to use a Group.

The example follows the sample code from abego which is capable of drawing multiple trees.  If you just want to generate and draw a single tree, it is simpler.

All of the JavaFX code is in the `com.example.treelayout.javafx` package, the rest of the code doesn't have anything to do with JavaFX.

[image: tree view]

*pom.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>treelayout</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>treelayout</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.abego.treelayout</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.abego.treelayout.core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>19</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>19</source>
                    <target>19</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

*module-info.java*

```
module com.example.treelayout {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires org.abego.treelayout.core;
    requires java.desktop;

    exports com.example.treelayout.javafx;
}
```

*com.example.treelayout.javafx.JavaFXDemo*

```
package com.example.treelayout.javafx;

import com.example.treelayout.SampleTreeFactory;
import com.example.treelayout.TextInBox;
import com.example.treelayout.TextInBoxNodeExtentProvider;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.abego.treelayout.TreeForTreeLayout;
import org.abego.treelayout.TreeLayout;
import org.abego.treelayout.util.DefaultConfiguration;

public class JavaFXDemo extends Application {

    private static final String[] TREE_NAMES = { "semtab", "semtab2", "2",  "" };

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        boolean boxVisible = true;
        for (String s: getParameters().getRaw()) {
            if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("--nobox")) {
                boxVisible = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        FlowPane layout = new FlowPane();
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(20));
        layout.setHgap(20);
        layout.setVgap(20);

        for (String treeName: TREE_NAMES) {
            layout.getChildren().add(
                    buildTree(treeName, boxVisible)
            );
        }

        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * Shows a tree in a layout created by {@link TreeLayout},
     * using the JavaFX component {@link TreeLayoutView}.
     */
    public TreeLayoutView buildTree(String treeName, boolean boxVisible) {
        TreeForTreeLayout<TextInBox> tree = getSampleTree(treeName);

        // setup the tree layout configuration
        double gapBetweenLevels = treeName.startsWith("semtab") ? 15 : 50;
        double gapBetweenNodes = 10;
        DefaultConfiguration<TextInBox> configuration = new DefaultConfiguration<>(
                gapBetweenLevels,
                gapBetweenNodes
        );

        // create the NodeExtentProvider for TextInBox nodes
        TextInBoxNodeExtentProvider nodeExtentProvider = new TextInBoxNodeExtentProvider();

        // create the layout
        TreeLayout<TextInBox> treeLayout = new TreeLayout<>(
                tree,
                nodeExtentProvider,
                configuration
        );

        // Create a panel that draws the nodes and edges and show the panel
        TreeLayoutView treePane = new TreeLayoutView(treeLayout);
        treePane.setBoxVisible(boxVisible);

        return treePane;
    }

    private TreeForTreeLayout<TextInBox> getSampleTree(String treeName) {
        return switch (treeName) {
            case "semtab" -> SampleTreeFactory.createSemanticTableaux();
            case "semtab2" -> SampleTreeFactory.createSemanticTableaux2();
            case "2" -> SampleTreeFactory.createSampleTree2();
            case "" -> SampleTreeFactory.createSampleTree();
            default -> throw new RuntimeException(
                    String.format(
                            "Invalid tree name: '%s'", treeName
                    )
            );
        };
    }

}
```

*com.example.treelayout.javafx.TreeLayoutView*

```
package com.example.treelayout.javafx;

import com.example.treelayout.TextInBox;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import org.abego.treelayout.TreeForTreeLayout;
import org.abego.treelayout.TreeLayout;

import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

/**
 * A JavaFX group displaying a tree of TextInBoxes, given by a {@link TreeLayout}.
 */
public class TreeLayoutView extends Group {
    private final TreeLayout<TextInBox> treeLayout;
    private boolean boxVisible = true;

    private TreeForTreeLayout<TextInBox> getTree() {
        return treeLayout.getTree();
    }

    private Iterable<TextInBox> getChildren(TextInBox parent) {
        return getTree().getChildren(parent);
    }

    private Rectangle2D.Double getBoundsOfNode(TextInBox node) {
        return treeLayout.getNodeBounds().get(node);
    }

    /**
     * Specifies the tree to be displayed by passing in a {@link TreeLayout} for
     * that tree.
     * 
     * @param treeLayout the {@link TreeLayout} to be displayed
     */
    public TreeLayoutView(TreeLayout<TextInBox> treeLayout) {
        this.treeLayout = treeLayout;

        addEdges(getTree().getRoot());

        // paint the boxes
        for (TextInBox textInBox : treeLayout.getNodeBounds().keySet()) {
            addBox(textInBox);
        }
    }

    public boolean isBoxVisible() {
        return boxVisible;
    }

    public void setBoxVisible(boolean boxVisible) {
        this.boxVisible = boxVisible;
    }

    private final static int ARC_SIZE = 10;
    private final static Color BOX_COLOR = Color.CORNSILK;
    private final static Color BORDER_COLOR = Color.DARKGRAY;
    private final static Color TEXT_COLOR = Color.BLACK;

    private void addEdges(TextInBox parent) {
        if (!getTree().isLeaf(parent)) {
            Rectangle2D.Double b1 = getBoundsOfNode(parent);
            double x1 = b1.getCenterX();
            double y1 = b1.getCenterY();
            for (TextInBox child : getChildren(parent)) {
                Rectangle2D.Double b2 = getBoundsOfNode(child);
                getChildren().add(
                        new Line(
                                x1, y1,
                                b2.getCenterX(), b2.getCenterY()
                        )
                );

                addEdges(child);
            }
        }
    }

    private void addBox(TextInBox textInBox) {
        Rectangle2D.Double box = getBoundsOfNode(textInBox);

        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(
                box.x, box.y, box.width - 1, box.height - 1
        );
        rectangle.setArcWidth(ARC_SIZE);
        rectangle.setArcHeight(ARC_SIZE);
        rectangle.setFill(BOX_COLOR);
        rectangle.setStroke(BORDER_COLOR);

        if (isBoxVisible()) {
            getChildren().add(
                    rectangle
            );
        }

        // draw the text on top of the box (possibly multiple lines)
        Label label = new Label(textInBox.text);
        label.setStyle("-fx-alignment: center; -fx-text-alignment: center; -fx-text-fill: " + colorStyleString(TEXT_COLOR) + ";");
        label.relocate(box.x, box.y);
        label.setMinSize(Label.USE_PREF_SIZE, Label.USE_PREF_SIZE);
        label.setPrefSize(box.width, box.height);
        label.setMaxSize(Label.USE_PREF_SIZE, Label.USE_PREF_SIZE);
        label.setWrapText(true);

        getChildren().add(label);
    }

    private String colorStyleString(Color color) {
        return "rgba("
                    + ((int) (color.getRed()   * 255)) + ","
                    + ((int) (color.getGreen() * 255)) + ","
                    + ((int) (color.getBlue()  * 255)) + ","
                    + color.getOpacity() +
                ")";
    }
}
```

*com.example.treelayout.TextInBox*

```
package com.example.treelayout;

/**
 * Represents a text to be displayed in a box of a given size.
 * 
 * @author Udo Borkowski (ub@abego.org)
 */
public class TextInBox {

    public final String text;
    public final int height;
    public final int width;

    public TextInBox(String text, int width, int height) {
        this.text = text;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }
}
```

*com.example.TextInBoxNodeExtentProvider*

```
package com.example.treelayout;

import org.abego.treelayout.NodeExtentProvider;

/**
 * A {@link NodeExtentProvider} for nodes of type {@link TextInBox}.
 * <p>
 * As one would expect this NodeExtentProvider returns the width and height as
 * specified with each TextInBox.
 * 
 * @author Udo Borkowski (ub@abego.org)
 */
public class TextInBoxNodeExtentProvider implements
        NodeExtentProvider<TextInBox> {

    @Override
    public double getWidth(TextInBox treeNode) {
        return treeNode.width;
    }

    @Override
    public double getHeight(TextInBox treeNode) {
        return treeNode.height;
    }
}
```

*com.example.treelayout.SampleTreeFactory*

```
package com.example.treelayout;

import org.abego.treelayout.TreeForTreeLayout;
import org.abego.treelayout.util.DefaultTreeForTreeLayout;

/**
 * Creates "Sample" trees, e.g. to be used in demonstrations.
 * 
 * @author Udo Borkowski (ub@abego.org)
 */
public class SampleTreeFactory {

    /**
     * @return a "Sample" tree with {@link TextInBox} items as nodes.
     */
    public static TreeForTreeLayout<TextInBox> createSampleTree() {
        TextInBox root = new TextInBox("root", 40, 20);
        TextInBox n1 = new TextInBox("n1", 30, 20);
        TextInBox n1_1 = new TextInBox("n1.1\n(first node)", 80, 36);
        TextInBox n1_2 = new TextInBox("n1.2", 40, 20);
        TextInBox n1_3 = new TextInBox("n1.3\n(last node)", 80, 36);
        TextInBox n2 = new TextInBox("n2", 30, 20);
        TextInBox n2_1 = new TextInBox("n2", 30, 20);

        DefaultTreeForTreeLayout<TextInBox> tree = new DefaultTreeForTreeLayout<TextInBox>(
                root);
        tree.addChild(root, n1);
        tree.addChild(n1, n1_1);
        tree.addChild(n1, n1_2);
        tree.addChild(n1, n1_3);
        tree.addChild(root, n2);
        tree.addChild(n2, n2_1);
        return tree;
    }

    /**
     * @return a "Sample" tree with {@link TextInBox} items as nodes.
     */
    public static TreeForTreeLayout<TextInBox> createSampleTree2() {
        TextInBox root = new TextInBox("prog", 40, 20);
        TextInBox n1 = new TextInBox("classDef", 65, 20);
        TextInBox n1_1 = new TextInBox("class", 50, 20);
        TextInBox n1_2 = new TextInBox("T", 20, 20);
        TextInBox n1_3 = new TextInBox("{", 20, 20);
        TextInBox n1_4 = new TextInBox("member", 60, 20);
        TextInBox n1_5 = new TextInBox("member", 60, 20);
        TextInBox n1_5_1 = new TextInBox("<ERROR:int>", 90, 20);
        TextInBox n1_6 = new TextInBox("member", 60, 20);
        TextInBox n1_6_1 = new TextInBox("int", 30, 20);
        TextInBox n1_6_2 = new TextInBox("i", 20, 20);
        TextInBox n1_6_3 = new TextInBox(";", 20, 20);
        TextInBox n1_7 = new TextInBox("}", 20, 20);


        DefaultTreeForTreeLayout<TextInBox> tree = new DefaultTreeForTreeLayout<TextInBox>(
                root);
        tree.addChild(root, n1);
        tree.addChild(n1, n1_1);
        tree.addChild(n1, n1_2);
        tree.addChild(n1, n1_3);
        tree.addChild(n1, n1_4);
        tree.addChild(n1, n1_5);
        tree.addChild(n1_5, n1_5_1);
        tree.addChild(n1, n1_6);
        tree.addChild(n1_6,n1_6_1);
        tree.addChild(n1_6,n1_6_2);
        tree.addChild(n1_6,n1_6_3);
        tree.addChild(n1, n1_7);
        return tree;
    }

    public static TreeForTreeLayout<TextInBox> createSemanticTableaux() {
        TextInBox root = new TextInBox(""+
                "((A -> B) & (B -> A))\n"+
                "(A -> B)\n"+
                "(B -> A)",
                140, 52);
        TextInBox n1_1_1 = new TextInBox("~A", 30, 20);
        TextInBox n1_1_2 = new TextInBox("B", 30, 20);
        TextInBox n1_1_1_1 = new TextInBox(""+
                "~B\n" +
                "OPEN", 44, 35);
        TextInBox n1_1_1_2 = new TextInBox(""+
                "A\n" +
                "X", 30, 35);
        TextInBox n1_1_2_1 = new TextInBox(""+
                "~B\n" +
                "X", 30, 35);
        TextInBox n1_1_2_2 = new TextInBox(""+
                "A\n" +
                "OPEN", 44, 35);


        DefaultTreeForTreeLayout<TextInBox> tree = new DefaultTreeForTreeLayout<TextInBox>(
                root);
        tree.addChild(root, n1_1_1);
        tree.addChild(root, n1_1_2);
        tree.addChild(n1_1_1, n1_1_1_1);
        tree.addChild(n1_1_1, n1_1_1_2);
        tree.addChild(n1_1_2, n1_1_2_1);
        tree.addChild(n1_1_2, n1_1_2_2);
        return tree;
    }

    public static TreeForTreeLayout<TextInBox> createSemanticTableaux2() {
        TextInBox root = new TextInBox("((A -> B) & (B -> A))", 140, 20);
        TextInBox n1 = new TextInBox("(A -> B)", 65, 20);
        TextInBox n1_1 = new TextInBox("(B -> A)", 65, 20);
        TextInBox n1_1_1 = new TextInBox("~A", 30, 20);
        TextInBox n1_1_2 = new TextInBox("B", 30, 20);
        TextInBox n1_1_1_1 = new TextInBox("~B", 30, 20);
        TextInBox n1_1_1_2 = new TextInBox("A", 30, 20);
        TextInBox n1_1_2_1 = new TextInBox("~B", 30, 20);
        TextInBox n1_1_2_2 = new TextInBox("A", 30, 20);
        TextInBox n1_1_1_1_1 = new TextInBox("OPEN", 44, 20);
        TextInBox n1_1_1_2_1 = new TextInBox("X", 20, 20);
        TextInBox n1_1_2_1_1 = new TextInBox("X", 20, 20);
        TextInBox n1_1_2_2_1 = new TextInBox("OPEN", 44, 20);


        DefaultTreeForTreeLayout<TextInBox> tree = new DefaultTreeForTreeLayout<TextInBox>(
                root);
        tree.addChild(root, n1);
        tree.addChild(n1, n1_1);
        tree.addChild(n1_1, n1_1_1);
        tree.addChild(n1_1, n1_1_2);
        tree.addChild(n1_1_1, n1_1_1_1);
        tree.addChild(n1_1_1, n1_1_1_2);
        tree.addChild(n1_1_2, n1_1_2_1);
        tree.addChild(n1_1_2, n1_1_2_2);
        tree.addChild(n1_1_1_1, n1_1_1_1_1);
        tree.addChild(n1_1_1_2, n1_1_1_2_1);
        tree.addChild(n1_1_2_1, n1_1_2_1_1);
        tree.addChild(n1_1_2_2,n1_1_2_2_1);
        return tree;
    }

}
```

Comment: i made it work in my setting, thanks for the help, i wouldn 't have guessed things like (`TreeLayoutView extends Group`)